# how do i configure spring 2.5.6 + eclipseLink + weblogic 10.3

Tags: spring, persistence, eclipselink, weblogic-10.x

```
    <bean id="configProperties" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="placeholderPrefix" value="${" />
    <property name="placeholderSuffix" value="}" />
    <property name="locations">
        <value>classpath:ddes/config.properties</value>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName" value="${datasource}"/>
    <property name="resourceRef" value="true"/>
</bean>

<context:load-time-weaver weaver-class="org.springframework.instrument.classloading.weblogic.WebLogicLoadTimeWeaver"/>

<bean id="PersistenceUnit" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.DefaultPersistenceUnitManager">
    <property name="defaultDataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="class">
    <!--LIST BEANS-->
        <value>....</value>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="jpaVendorAdapter" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.EclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter">
    <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.eclipse.persistence.platform.database.OraclePlatform"/>
    <property name="generateDdl" value="true"/>
    <property name="showSql" value="true"/>
</bean>

<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="jpaVendorAdapter"/>
    <property name="persistenceUnitManager" ref="PersistenceUnit"/>
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" ref="Persistence-ejbPU"/>
    <property name="persistenceProvider" ref="org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider"/>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager">
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
</bean>
```

implement

```
@CallByReference
@Stateless(mappedName = "cliente") 
public class ClienteDAOBean implements ClienteDAOLocal, ClienteDAORemote {


    @PersistenceUnit(unitName = "Persistence-ejbPU")
    private EntityManagerFactory emf;

    public Clientes find(Integer codCliente) throws Exception {
        Clientes cliente = null;
        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
        try {
            javax.persistence.Query q = em.createNamedQuery("Clientes.findByCodCliente").setParameter("codCliente", codCliente);
            cliente = (Clientes) q.getSingleResult();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw e;
        } finally {
            em.close();
            return cliente;
        }
    }
}
```

Pero al iniciar la aplicación el log arroja este error:

**No persistence unit named 'Persistence-ejbPU' is available in scope Persistence-ejbPU.jar**

was previously using a persistence.xml file but needed the name of the datasource out dynamic

Comment: Well, I don't see a bean identified as `Persistence-ejbPU` in your configuration file. (Also, don't mix spanish and english in your question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply replace ref with value. Use:

```
 <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="Persistence-ejbPU" />
```

instead of:

```
<property name="persistenceUnitName" ref="Persistence-ejbPU"/>
```

If you are having still problem then I would implement my own *LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean* class which extends from [AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/orm/jpa/AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.html) so you can override **setPersistenceUnitName** then see what is going on.